# javascript menubar and form

Tags: javascript, html, menubar

I have my main page "index.html" with the following code for the menubar:

```
<head>
    <script>
    function eco_para(clicked_id) {
    clicked_id1="#" + clicked_id
    $("#home").removeClass("fired");
    $("#inputdata").removeClass("fired");
    $("#contact").removeClass("fired");
    $(clicked_id1).addClass("fired");
    {{$.get(clicked_id + '.html',function (data) { $('section').html(data)});};};
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <menu>
                <mi id="home" class="fired" onclick="location.reload()">Acceuil</a></mi>
                <mi id="inputdata" onclick="eco_para(this.id)">Calculateur</mi>
                <mi id="contact" onclick="eco_para(this.id)">Contact </a></mi>
            </menu>
        </header>
        <section>
        </section>  
    </div>
</body>
```

On the page inputdata.html, i use a form with a submit button:

```
<form  method="post" action="result.html">
<input type="submit" value="Compute">
</form>
```

The problem is that the "submit" button loads the page "result.html" and the menu disappears. In other words, the menu is lost because the action of the form does not load the result.html using the javascript of index.html page.

I have a quick and dirty solution which is to copy/paste the code of the index.html to the result.html but i don't think it is the best way as i will have to maintain 2 codes for one menu.

what is the best way to proceed? (i am new to javacsript / html) I want to follow the best practice.
1) Is there a way to call the code from index.html through another page?
2) Is there a way to load a page in a section from another page with a javascript code?

thanks for your help!

**UPDATE 11-oct**
Actually i haven't managed to make much progress even with the answer from CP500.
Here is another simplified example:
When i load the page contact.html, i want this page to load within the section of the page index.html
I tried to use that code but actually it does not work (code in contact.html):

```
<script>
$(function() {
$.get( "contact.html", function( data ) { $("index.html:section").html(data);});
})
</script>
```

I don't know how to force the contact.html to load within the section of index.html...

thanks!

Comment: You need ajax to load the form result also. And a preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

The method you seem to be hinting at is AJAX, or (a)synchronous HTTP requests. Using jQuery or native XHR you can achieve this idea.

**jQuery method**

```
$.get('result.html', 
     {'inputName': $('#inputID').val()},
     function(data) { [returned html is in 'data'] }
);
```

This method requires you to use the jQuery javascript library (free and online). Then what this does is sends a GET request to `result.html`, supplies the input values for the query, and fires a callback with the response data.

If your server runs PHP or even RoR you could employ templating techniques to have the server automatically structure the HTML delivered by including the menu templates.

**PHP method**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```